# Getting proper 'this' value in tippy.js

Tags: javascript, tippyjs

When a [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)
tooltip is triggered, I want to be able to get "this" from it.
I've tried:

```
tippy(".sampleID",{
    arrow:true,
    placement: "bottom",
  content(reference) {                            
    const title = reference.getAttribute('title'); 
    var tid=$(this).attr("id"); // is undefined
    return title;
  }
});
```

How do I get "this" for class .sampleID that was hovered on?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/rqx9vj8n/10/)

Comment: What should `this` refer to? The tooltip? The element it's anchored to? Please post an MVCE example with what `this` is expected to refer to.

Comment: this for .sampleID

Comment: Ok, do you mean the HTML element that matches that selector? The one the tooltip is anchored to? Don't forget you can pass an element directly instead of a selector, and the content function would close over the reference.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to the question.

Comment: I want "this" for the input box, who's class is .sampleID

Comment: Can't you not just use `reference` instead? It already contains your element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `reference` provided as the argument, which refers to the current element matching `.sampleID`.

In your case I think you're trying to access the parent element though, which contains your `id`.

```
  tippy(".sampleID",{
    arrow:true,
    placement: "bottom",
    content(reference) {                              
      const title = reference.getAttribute('title');
      const tid = reference.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
      // jQuery: const tid = $(reference).parent().data('id');
      return title+"<br>"+tid;
    }
  });
```